# How would I get the current value of a dynamically created Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm currently getting the value of a dropdown menu on change, and then adding it to the id of a div that surrounds the dropdown menu.

I'm wanting to be able to use this value later on in my code but right now it seems that I'm getting an undefined variable probably because it's not assigned on page load.

What would be a good way/better way of getting this value or assigning the value to a variable? And what would be a good way of reloading or refreshing the page so that it can be updated to the new variable?

I want to use the selectedValue var in the if statement instead of the "Big 12".

The person who suggested it was the same as another question I don't think is understanding my question.

Any ideas?

```
$('#team-select').change(function() {
    var teamSelect = $(this).val();
   $('.select-team-menu').attr('id', teamSelect); 

});

var selectedValue = $('.select-team-menu').attr('id');
console.log(selectedValue);

    getGames().done(function(results){
        $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
            $.each(gameData, function(key, game){

                var gamesHome = game.home_team_conference;
                var gamesAway = game.away_team_conference;




                if(gamesHome == "Big 12" || gamesAway == "Big 12"){
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Not enough known about what you are trying to do. Although `var selectedValue =...` is looking for something before it exists in the change event you also don't show how you use it

Comment: That is unclear how you use `selectedValue` after page load... But since it is defined on load, and the "source" of its value is modified on `change`... **Source change does not reflect in the variable value**. Whatever happens after `load` is out of "scope". Then you also have an async function running...

Comment: @charlietfl if you read I explain where I would use it and I already knew that it doesn't exist yet. I'm looking for a better way to do this. I'm going to use the selectedValue var in the if statement.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette should I just use a submit button and then reload the page with that value? Would that make things easier?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to do all this after the event occurs by wrapping it in a function and calling that function in `change` callback

Comment: To set the variable value **in** the `change` handler would be a start. (Kepp the onload value setting to have a value before change)... So just copy the line `var selectedValue = $('.select-team-menu').attr('id');` in the change handler and look if that solves the thing.

Comment: @charlietfl thank you I think this is the answer I might be looking for. So just do a function and then call the function on change?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette How would you suggest I do that, I've been trying to do this haha.

Comment: Yes and you can pass in that new value

Comment: @charlietfl if you could possibly write that out for me so I can better understand I can mark that as the best answer.

Comment: Its ONE line to copy! One you already have...

Comment: Ha... okay... In the handler, just skip the `var` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `getGames()` in another function that you can call when the change event occurs

```
$('#team-select').change(function() {
    var teamSelect = $(this).val();
   $('.select-team-menu').attr('id', teamSelect);    
   // call function declared below and pass in new value from <select>
   loadSelectedTeam(teamSelect);
});


// declare function anywhere in file
function loadSelectedTeam(selectedValue){    
    getGames().done(function(results){
       $.each...    
          ....
           // use selectedValue passed into function
           if(gamesHome == selectedValue  || gamesAway == selectedValue ){....
```

Comment: Wow... How did you get the OP objective? I presume experience. ;) +1

Comment: Ok one more question, now it seems to be loading them all every time I change the drop down input, it just adds them to the page instead of getting rid of the old ones and replacing them with the new ones.

Comment: My guess is you are using `append()`. Use `empty()` on that container before you start any append()

Comment: Ok I'll try that out.

Comment: Ok you are amazing, thank you for your help, that fixed my problem! Seriously this was giving me such a headache. Thanks again! I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem brad. That's what this site is all about

Comment: Actually could have done the exact same thing by just moving the closing braces for `change()` below all the other code. But breaking it up makes it far easier to manage. Wrapping it into a function allows that